# How long do competitor stocks go up after you complete an assassination mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was just wondering when to sell the stocks. Do they hit a plateau, or if they just keep on going up?

EDIT:

It seems to be different for each stock. Most of them will hit a plateau though I've found, so you're really going to want to sell them before it drops back. Don't get greedy and wait it out, when the price is basically stable at the top, sell it quick. On the multiple judge assassination, I waited too long. Went to +50%, stayed there a day or so, then tanked right back down.

I'm accepting the answer with the guide though, because it's a rather helpful one.

Comment: Or do they eventually tank?

Comment: And the flip side... do stocks ever recover after an assassination? Because if so, right afterwards is a great time to buy low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will usually rise for a couple days. Since I was doing some of them during my main story playthrough I would do an assassination mission and then do a couple main story missions and then go and sell off the stock I had in those companies. I'd say a good rule of thumb is to wait a couple days and to check on the stock prices periodically. Once you notice it is tapering off then sell.

I found [this stock market guide](http://geekfed.com/grand-theft-auto-5-stock-market-tips/323) to be useful as well.

Comment: That's a great guide.

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 2):

They plateau at a point.  I bought a bunch of Debonaire stock, sold it right after the mission and then decided to buy it back to see if the price would keep rising.  After the rebuy, the price went down a bit and I lost money.  I've found that selling within 24 hours will get you your best profit return.

Comment: I just tested this after my latest mission(hotel assassination), kept sleeping and saving. It's been 3 days and it seems to be going up still. Maybe it's kind of random? I've been searching more and it seems like it goes up a bunch and then goes up more slowly?

Comment: My debonaire stock dropped back down too. We should collect some experimental data on this, maybe it's predetermined.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get them up 80.46% just pretty much sitting in the portfolio screen and refreshing it, and then sold in a Multiple Targets Assasination. However, Betapharm stock only went up to 40 something, and then I turned the console on the next day and they were like 20 up, so I sold.

I've noticed that they skyrocket for some time and at some point get steady, so my refreshes were like 22 -> 25 -> 27 -> 30 -> 34 -> 37 -> 40 .. -> 79 -> 79.5 -> 79.9 -> 80.15 -> 80.20 -> 80.25 -> 80.40 -> 80.46 and then I sold.

Answer (score 1):

They will go up immediately and rise for about 12 in-game hours. They normally leap to ~20% and rise quickly to ~40% and will stay their for the rest of the time. It's a good idea to simply check the stock market after completing the mission and waiting for it to go over 40%, then sell it all. It won't go higher.

Comment: I've had it go up to 80%, so that can't be correct. Maybe it varies on different stocks though.

Comment: The last one goes up to about 80% but the others shouldn't. I think the first one only goes up to about 30%

Comment: Got 98% return on the second mission stock (debonaire). Bought just over $200 (during the mission, as soon as I hung up with Lester)  and sold for $502.  It hovered at $502 for some time, gaining and losing $1 for a bit before I sold.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done two assassinations so far, hotel and multiple. The hotel one where you buy bettapharmaceuticals, the stocks peaked at 50% so then sell everything. The multiple one where you buy debonaire, those stocks peaked at 82.63% so again sell when it hits that. I found these out just buy clicking portfolio n refreshing, they slowly start going down after they hit those figures.

Answer (score -1):

Also a good thing to take note is that the Bawsaq market is not available unless you sign into playstation/xbox online, my guess being that the stock values are actually based on trades occurring in the virtual GTA world.